# Error while building React Native project (yarn android) - not found C compiler

Tags: react-native, cmake

I am using React Native and Android Studio. An error occurs

```
> Task :ReactAndroid:hermes-engine:configureBuildForHermes FAILED
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

In log file:

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: -c

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: -Aa

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: -c

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: -Aa

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: -c

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: --c++

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: --ec++

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags:

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: -c

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: --c++

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: --ec++

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: cl
Build flags:
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3

The output was:
Не удается найти указанный файл

Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":

Seems like cmake can't find C compiler files. How fix this error?

cmake v 3.18.1, react-native v 0.70

Comment: the English error message might help to add to your post - Google Translate says "Cannot find the specified file"